# Retrieve the Last Known Location when the smartphone was turned off a long time

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm working on an Android project and the application needs the GPS coordinates to work.

So after a long sleep, the line of code below give me null when I try to get the coordinates

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location _lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

So to get them, I've to start Google Maps which is a little bit disapointing . I already read a lot of threads but anyone really helpful. I'm using a **Samsung S2** and a **S3** but I also read that the cause is a bug in the native service which stuck in a loop trying to restart itslef.

> **Is anybody know how can I figure this out?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Geolocation of your device, you can use many providers, such as [LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER), [LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER) and [LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER).

You will find more infos in [Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) guideline

Comment: Thks for your answer but the provider I use is GPS_PROVIDER. I tested with NETWORK_PROVIDER but nothing. I also the specific permissions to get GPS Coordinates