# Why activate GPS is not enough to get user's position?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm working on an Android project which give the user the possibility to turn on his GPS. His position is requested to launch the application.

After activation, I use getLastKnownLocation of LocationManager but this method returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the given provider. The doc explains that this can be done without starting the provider. Note that this location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned off and moved to another location.

However the user activate localization services. So turn on the GPS is not enough to launch the GPS as it's done by Google Maps by showing an icon at the top of the device and retrieving GPS coordinates. This icon doesn't appear when my application gives the user the possibility to activate the GPS (seems weird).

Theards I already read use getLastKnownLocation method after choosing the best provider. Questions are did I miss something after turning on the GPS services? Did the GPS is automatically launch when the GPS is activated?

I already ask [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067751/retrieve-the-last-known-location-when-the-smartphone-was-turned-off-a-long-time), but not enough answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for showing blue dot icon on map use this line

```
map_fragment.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

use this code to get location where you want to get location

```
      GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(this);
            Double latiDouble = gps.getLatitude();


            Double  loDouble = gps.getLongitude();
```

create a class GPSTracker and add this code

```
    public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    boolean isGPSEnabled=false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled=false;
    boolean canGetLocation=false;
    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES=10;  //10 meters
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES=1000*60*1; //1 minute
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context)
    {
        this.mContext=context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation()
    {
        locationManager=(LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
        {
            //showSettingAlert();
        }
        else
        {
            this.canGetLocation=true;

            if(isGPSEnabled)
            {
                if(location==null)
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);
                }
                if(locationManager != null)
                {
                    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if(location != null)
                    {
                        latitude=location.getLatitude();
                        longitude=location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            if(isNetworkEnabled)
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,this);
                if(locationManager!=null)
                {
                    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if(location!=null)
                            {
                                latitude=location.getLatitude();
                                longitude=location.getLongitude();
                            }
                }
            }

        }
        return location;
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS()
    {
        if(locationManager!=null)
        {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude()
    {
        if(location != null)
        {
            latitude=location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude()
    {
        if(location != null)
        {
            longitude=location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation(){
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingAlert()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled .Do you want to go to settings menu ?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, turning on GPS is not enough, you also need a Location Listener to listen to updates of position.

Something like in [Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
        makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
};

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```